# Actions and objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I would like to create a custom action  XXX "got nailed at" (nail polish promotion for a chain of stores) with the object being one of the physical store locations i.e. got nailed at XXX store in London or Got nailed at XXX store in NY.

Is this possible?

Also, when it comes to submitting action and object types, is this vetted by a human at Facebook? Or is this an automated process?

Comment: +1 "XXX got nailed" - awesome idea BTW :P

Answer (score 0):

All the things you have listed here are very possible.  I haven't dealt too much with custom Open Graph actions but I'll get you started with some information taken from the [Facebook Documentation on the Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).
Here are some guide lines for the approval process of your custom actions :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/

There is no reference to whether is it "human verified" there might be some sort of initial filtering of obscenities or some other filter of "saved words" but ultimately I would imagine there is a good possibility that it is reviewed manually (at least to some stage).

---

Another reason I chose to answer was that little "yet" (in brackets).

- The official [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) contains a wealth of information about developing on and for Facebook's platform.
- The [Facebook Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) that contains lots of tutorials about basic and advanced techniques.

Comment: Thanks Lix, appreciate your feedback. I have read all of the documentation you mentioned as well as setting up a test app with the mentioned actions and objects. It looks like it should would ok. My problem at the moment is specifying the object and appending the location of the store to the ticker/newsfeed/timeline. Again, Thanks for your assistance.